# jQuery $(this) selector within plugin call

Tags: jquery

I am currently integrating a jQuery plugin called [RangeSlider JS](https://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/).

This is the function in which I fire the plugin:

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
    param: true, 
    param2: false,

    onInit: function() {    
        if ($(this).attr('name') === 'someName') {
            // do something ... 
        },
    }
});
```

Now, since I have more than one inputs of the type "range" that I am using the plugin for, I need to distinguish each input. I am trying to do this by getting the input's "name" attribute, but it seems like `$(this)` is not working from within that function.

Any ideas how to make the `$(this)` selector work? `$(this)` should refer to the `input[type="range"]`.

Comment: can you provide some live example in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yt6ogjx7/ - JS part looks messy because I pasted the plugin code in, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to look at the [actual JS source code for that plugin](https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js/blob/develop/src/rangeslider.js) to see how `onInit()` is called, but it looks like, `this` is set to a rangeslider `Plugin` object.  And, `this.$element` will get you a jQuery object for the current element.

So, you should be able to do this:

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
    param: true, 
    param2: false,

    onInit: function() {    
        if (this.$element.attr('name') === 'someName') {
            // do something ... 
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: A good step to figuring out what you're dealing with is to do a `console.log(this);` and see if it is actually what you think it is. Might save a little mucking around in source :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate the results and store a reference to the current control.

```
$('input[type="range"]').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.rangeslider({
    param: true, 
    param2: false,
    onInit: function() {    
      if (that.attr('name') === 'someName') {
        // do something ... 
      },
    }
  });      
});
```